# ios-charts LineChartView. How to select part of the chart

Tags: ios, swift, linechart, ios-charts

what I want to do is the following. I have a linechart with some data points on it. I want to allow user to select chunk of the chart and highlight it by dragging a finger.

I tried a few hacky approaches using ChartTransformer and tracking pixels of the UIPanGestureRecognizer and then programmatically highlighting the appropriate xIndexes, but it looks terrible.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say your approaches should be right, what you mean it looks terrible?

I would check when the pan gesture ended, I will calculate how many xIndex has been chosen, and highlight every data entry for that Index.

The logic to determine the xIndex - when user start panning, I know the location, and I will translate it into the closest xIndex; same as the ending point, so we know the start xIndex and end xIndex

Comment: var pixel = CGPoint(x: x, y: 0);transformer.pixelToValue(&pixel)                        That's kinda how I'm trying to get the xIndex, but the problem is that pixelToValue doesn't give me the right xIndex. What happens is that: it gives me the xIndex of the nearest visible label. Since I have 140 points and about 4 labels (because those are time labels), I can't get the precision I need.